# Discord.py - Command isn't registering all of my arguments

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was trying to create a command where it would be able to create a role, channel, and give that same role it created to someone you mentioned.

My code:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
  async def newrealm(self, ctx, realm, emoji,  user: discord.Member):
    reason = realm.split(' ')
    realm, emoji , user = reason
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    color = discord.Colour(0x3498DB)
    role = await guild.create_role(name= realm + " OP", color = color)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name = "Realm Channels List Test")
    await category.create_text_channel(realm + "-" + emoji)
    await ctx.send("Created Channel and Role!")
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Command I am sending:
`>newrealm testrealm :cheese: @SpaceRanger_Pro`

What it should do is create a new channel called #testrealm-:cheese:, then create a new role called testrealm OP. (At this point everything worked) The only issue the command is having is being able to give that new role (in this case testrealm OP) to the person I mentioned.

Traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command newrealm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SolarisTurtleMain/cogs/RealmCMD.py", line 62, in newrealm
    realm, emoji , user = reason
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Any helps or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `reason` and `realm` are strings without spaces taking in the realm name that the user passes in. You don't even need to unpack those values. You are already taking them in as an argument. Remove `reason = realm.split(' ')` and `realm, emoji , user = reason` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

All of the arguments in the `newrealm` function can be referenced directly. You are treating them like one big string. When you are trying to split `realm`, you are telling it to only split `testrealm` in the case of your test command. The error lets you know by saying that there is not enough values to unpack. It is to be split 3 times since you gave it 3 variables to assign. Then when you try to assign the 3 variables, realm, emoji, and user, to the "split" string, `reason`, you are simply setting `user` equal to `realm`, so `testrealm`, since there is nothing to split.

Try deleting the lines:

```
reason = realm.split(' ')
realm, emoji , user = reason
```

and It will most likely work.